# Get IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio Opened Project Folder with ElectronJS Application

Tags: windows, android-studio, intellij-idea, electron

I'm trying to make an application which can communicate with android studio, but IntelliJ plugin SDK is not giving me enough option to build the features that I want, so I'm thinking about trying a different approach to create a separate windows application for functionality but as application needs to know the project folder that is currently opened with android studio, I'm trying to search the same from 4-5 days but haven't found anything helpful if this is possible to read folder location of open project in android studio with a different application please help me, if there is some way that building plugin that can send location to external application please tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just manage to achieve the same with WPF, still don't know if electron can do it or not

if someone is finding the answer for this here's my approach, not the best and final but just figured out how I can do it make sure you will optimize code before implementation

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            var allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
            String data = "";

            for(int a =0; a < allProcesses.Length; a++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                if (allProcesses[a].MainWindowTitle.Contains("Android"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                    data = allProcesses[a].MainWindowTitle;

                    if(data.Contains("["))
                    { 

                    data = data.Substring(data.IndexOf("["));
                    data= data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf("]") + 1);

                    data = data.Replace("[", "");
                    data = data.Replace("]", "");

                    Console.WriteLine(data);

                    MessageBox.Show(data);


                    return;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Project is not open in Android Studio");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Android Studio Not Running");
            return;

        }
```